Efficiently simulating many frequency-severity distributions over thousands of iterations in numpy
I've got a problem at work that goes as follows:
We have, say, 1 million possible events which define frequency-severity distributions.
For each event we have an annual rate which defines a Poisson distribution, and alpha and beta parameters for a Beta distributions. The goal is to simulate in the order of >100,000 "years", each year being defined as getting a frequency N for each event, and getting N samples of the relative beta distribution.
The cumbersome fact for me is how can I efficiently get N_i ~ Poisson(lambda_i) samples from Beta distribution Beta_i while also making sure I can attribute them to the correct year?
In terms of output I'll need to look at both the maximum and total value of the samples per year, so temporarily I'm just storing it
as an array of dictionaries (not intended to be the output format)
years = 5000

rng = np.random.default_rng()
losses = []
for year in range(years):
  occurences = rng.poisson(data['RATE'])
  annual_losses = []
  for idx, occs in enumerate(occurences):
    if occs > 0:
      event = data.iloc[idx]
      for occ in range(occs):
        loss = rng.beta(event['alpha'], event['beta']) * event['ExpValue']
        annual_losses.append(loss)
  annual_losses.append(0)
  losses.append({'year': year, 'losses': annual_losses})

I've tried to follow Optimising Python/Numpy code used for Simulation however I can't seem to understand how to vectorise this code efficiently.
Changes I've made before posting here are (times for 5000 years):

swapping from scipy to numpy (72s -> 66s)
calculating frequencies for all years in once outside the loop (66s -> 73s... oops)

Ideally I'd like this to run as fast, or for as many iterations, as possible, and I was also running into issues with memory using scipy previously.
EDIT:
Upon request here's a version that just calculates the maximum loss for each year
years = 20_000

rng = np.random.default_rng()
largest_losses = np.zeros(shape=years)
for year in range(years):
  occurences = rng.poisson(data['RATE'])
  largest_loss = 0
  for idx, event_occs in enumerate(occurences):
    if event_occs > 0:
      event = data.iloc[idx]
      for event_occ in range(event_occs):
        loss = rng.beta(event['alpha'], event['beta']) * event['ExpValue']
        if loss > largest_loss:
          largest_loss = loss
  largest_losses[year] = largest_loss

For testing purposes the events have a total rate of ~0.997 and the timed tests above are from an event pool of 100,604 events.
To specify the goal, I'd like to see if I can calculate the percentiles of the losses, e.g. the 1-in-250 loss
np.percentile(largest_losses, (1 - 1/250) * 100)

which currently aren't accurate at 5,000, hence wanting a process that can run in a few minutes or less for ~100,000 years.
EDIT 2: Reproduceable values (as np arrays):
rate_scale = 4.81e-4
rate_shape = 2.06e-2
rates = rng.gamma(rate_shape, rate_scale, size=nevents)

alpha_scale = 1.25
alpha_shape = 0.439
alphas = rng.gamma(alpha_shape, alpha_scale, size=nevents)

beta_scale = 289
beta_shape = 0.346
betas = rng.gamma(beta_shape, beta_scale, size=nevents)

value_scale = 4.2e8
value_shape = 1.0
values = rng.gamma(value_shape, value_scale, size=nevents)

and have amended my current code to use numpy arrays
years = 20_000

rng = np.random.default_rng()
largest_losses = np.zeros(shape=years)
for year in range(years):
  occurences = rng.poisson(rates)
  largest_loss = 0
  for idx, event_occs in enumerate(occurences):
    for event_occ in range(event_occs):
      loss = rng.beta(alphas[idx], betas[idx]) * values[idx]
      if loss > largest_loss:
        largest_loss = loss
  largest_losses[year] = largest_loss

f'{np.percentile(largest_losses, (1 - 1/250) * 100):,.0f}'


Can you create a minimal, reproducible example of the behavior you want to see?

"In terms of output I'll need to look at both the maximum and total value of the samples per year, so temporarily I'm just storing it as an array of dictionaries (not intended to be the output format)" If you change this code so that it reports just sum and max values, rather than all values, that will give answer writers more freedom to optimize.

You say your times are for 5000 years. Did you use 1 million possible events for those times?

@WarrenWeckesser there were 100,604 events for my time testing, with a total rate across all events of ~0.997 (for frequency calculations) - hopefully this gives an idea of the number of calculations performed

@NickODell I've amended the code to include a maximum yearly loss example and specified the parameters that lead to my specific times

@DiogoSantos Thanks. Can you make the example reproducible? We still don't have the value of data. Is Warren Weckesser's guess at your initial data reasonable?

@NickODell I've included parameters for getting some dummy data based one the values present in my data - it performs slightly slower than my actual data (5% difference on Warrens method, 25% on my method) however it's in the same order of magnitude so hopefully that's close enough

I profiled @WarrenWeckesser's answer, and I found that it spends 93% of its time generating poisson-distributed numbers using the rate array.
Here's a line profile of what I'm talking about:
Timer unit: 1e-09 s

Total time: 3.57874 s
File: /tmp/ipykernel_2774/1125349843.py
Function: simulate_warren_answer at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def simulate_warren_answer(nyears, rate, alpha, beta, value, rng):
     2         1      13092.0  13092.0      0.0      max_loss = np.zeros(nyears, dtype=np.float64)
     3         1       3150.0   3150.0      0.0      total_loss = np.zeros(nyears, dtype=np.float64)
     4      1001     347152.0    346.8      0.0      for year in range(nyears):
     5      1000 3355879564.0    3e+06     93.8          n = rng.poisson(rate)
     6      1000  179118381.0 179118.4      5.0          k = np.nonzero(n)[0]
     7      1000     911231.0    911.2      0.0          if len(k) > 0:
     8       654     935876.0   1431.0      0.0              nonzero_n = n[k]
     9       654    4049698.0   6192.2      0.1              a = np.repeat(alpha[k], nonzero_n)
    10       654    2645836.0   4045.6      0.1              b = np.repeat(beta[k], nonzero_n)
    11       654    2550944.0   3900.5      0.1              v = np.repeat(value[k], nonzero_n)
    12       654   26183513.0  40036.0      0.7              losses = rng.beta(a, b)*v
    13       654    3557136.0   5439.0      0.1              max_loss[year] = losses.max()
    14       654    2543208.0   3888.7      0.1              total_loss[year] = losses.sum()
    15         1        303.0    303.0      0.0      return max_loss, total_loss

For this reason, I started looking into whether it was possible to speed up poisson-distributed random number generation. I started by looking at the lengths of n and k, and realized that for the rates that the asker is interested in, k is much much smaller than n, and most entries in n are zero.
If there is a 98% chance that the poisson-distributed number will be zero, I can simulate this by generating a uniformly distributed random number between [0, 1), and comparing it to 0.02. This leaves me to handle the other case 2% of the time, where the number will be 1+.
I then realized that I could generalize this to generating any value of the poisson function, by comparing the random uniform value to the CDF. (In the code below, I am using the survival function, which is 1-CDF. This is for accuracy reasons; numbers near 0 are represented more accurately than numbers near 1.)
This code generates a lookup table for converting uniformly-distributed numbers into poisson-distributed numbers according to each rate. Because the rates are small, most of the time, the code will only need to examine the first entry for each rate, and the result will be zero. It also does the k = np.nonzero(n)[0] step inside this loop, as it is more cache efficient.
Because the rates are not changing, the lookup table only needs to be build once, and can be re-used between years.
import scipy
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


def simulate_new_rng(nyears, rate, alpha, beta, value, rng):
    max_loss = np.empty(nyears, dtype=np.float64)
    total_loss = np.zeros(nyears, dtype=np.float64)
    lookup = build_lookup(rate)
    for year in range(nyears):
        uniform = rng.random(len(rate))
        n, nonzeros = uniform_to_poisson_plus_nonzero(uniform, lookup)
        n_nonzeros = n[nonzeros]
        a = np.repeat(alpha[nonzeros], n_nonzeros)
        b = np.repeat(beta[nonzeros], n_nonzeros)
        v = np.repeat(value[nonzeros], n_nonzeros)
        losses = rng.beta(a, b)*v
        max_loss[year] = losses.max(initial=0)
        total_loss[year] = losses.sum()
    return max_loss, total_loss


def build_lookup(rate, ptol=1e-15):
    """Build uniform -> poisson lookup table based on survival function
    
    Does not include an entry for k if the probability of the most likely
    rate to be k is less than ptol."""
    ret = []
    for k in itertools.count():
        sf = scipy.stats.poisson.sf(k, rate)
        # include first row of lookup table no matter what
        if sf.max() < ptol and k != 0:
            break
        ret.append(sf)
    return np.array(ret)


@nb.njit()
def uniform_to_poisson_plus_nonzero(numbers, lookup):
    assert numbers.shape[0] == lookup.shape[1]
    nonzeros = []
    ret = np.empty(lookup.shape[1], dtype=np.int64)
    for j in range(lookup.shape[1]):
        number = numbers[j]
        for i in range(lookup.shape[0]):
            if number < lookup[i, j]:
                continue
            else:
                break
        else:
            raise Exception("failed to find match for survival function - ptol is too big")
        ret[j] = i
        if i != 0:
            nonzeros.append(j)
    return ret, np.array(nonzeros, dtype=np.int64)

Benchmark result:
Original code: 24.4 s ± 308 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Warrens answer: 3.44 s ± 18.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
My answer: 648 ms ± 17.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Appendix: Full benchmarking code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
import scipy
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


rng = np.random.default_rng()
nevents = 100604
nyears = 1000

rate_scale = 4.81e-4
rate_shape = 2.06e-2
rates = rng.gamma(rate_shape, rate_scale, size=nevents)

alpha_scale = 1.25
alpha_shape = 0.439
alphas = rng.gamma(alpha_shape, alpha_scale, size=nevents)

beta_scale = 289
beta_shape = 0.346
betas = rng.gamma(beta_shape, beta_scale, size=nevents)

value_scale = 4.2e8
value_shape = 1.0
values = rng.gamma(value_shape, value_scale, size=nevents)


def simulate_orig_answer(nyears, rate, alpha, beta, value, rng):
    data = pd.DataFrame({'RATE': rate, 'alpha': alpha, 'beta': beta, 'ExpValue': value})
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    largest_losses = np.zeros(shape=nyears)
    total_loss = np.zeros(nyears, dtype=np.float64)
    for year in range(nyears):
        occurences = rng.poisson(data['RATE'])
        largest_loss = 0
        sum_loss = 0
        for idx, event_occs in enumerate(occurences):
            if event_occs > 0:
                event = data.iloc[idx]
                for event_occ in range(event_occs):
                    loss = rng.beta(event['alpha'], event['beta']) * event['ExpValue']
                    if loss > largest_loss:
                        largest_loss = loss
                    sum_loss += loss
        largest_losses[year] = largest_loss
        total_loss[year] = sum_loss
    return largest_losses, total_loss


def simulate_warren_answer(nyears, rate, alpha, beta, value, rng):
    max_loss = np.zeros(nyears, dtype=np.float64)
    total_loss = np.zeros(nyears, dtype=np.float64)
    for year in range(nyears):
        n = rng.poisson(rate)
        k = np.nonzero(n)[0]
        if len(k) > 0:
            nonzero_n = n[k]
            a = np.repeat(alpha[k], nonzero_n)
            b = np.repeat(beta[k], nonzero_n)
            v = np.repeat(value[k], nonzero_n)
            losses = rng.beta(a, b)*v
            max_loss[year] = losses.max()
            total_loss[year] = losses.sum()
    return max_loss, total_loss


def simulate_new_rng(nyears, rate, alpha, beta, value, rng):
    max_loss = np.empty(nyears, dtype=np.float64)
    total_loss = np.zeros(nyears, dtype=np.float64)
    lookup = build_lookup(rate)
    for year in range(nyears):
        uniform = rng.random(len(rate))
        n, nonzeros = uniform_to_poisson_plus_nonzero(uniform, lookup)
        n_nonzeros = n[nonzeros]
        a = np.repeat(alpha[nonzeros], n_nonzeros)
        b = np.repeat(beta[nonzeros], n_nonzeros)
        v = np.repeat(value[nonzeros], n_nonzeros)
        losses = rng.beta(a, b)*v
        max_loss[year] = losses.max(initial=0)
        total_loss[year] = losses.sum()
    return max_loss, total_loss


def build_lookup(rate, ptol=1e-15):
    """Build uniform -> poisson lookup table based on survival function
    
    Does not include an entry for k if the probability of the most likely
    rate to be k is less than ptol."""
    ret = []
    for k in itertools.count():
        sf = scipy.stats.poisson.sf(k, rate)
        # include first row of lookup table no matter what
        if sf.max() < ptol and k != 0:
            break
        ret.append(sf)
    return np.array(ret)


@nb.njit()
def uniform_to_poisson_plus_nonzero(numbers, lookup):
    assert numbers.shape[0] == lookup.shape[1]
    nonzeros = []
    ret = np.empty(lookup.shape[1], dtype=np.int64)
    for j in range(lookup.shape[1]):
        number = numbers[j]
        for i in range(lookup.shape[0]):
            if number < lookup[i, j]:
                continue
            else:
                break
        else:
            raise Exception("failed to find match for survival function - ptol is too big")
        ret[j] = i
        if i != 0:
            nonzeros.append(j)
    return ret, np.array(nonzeros, dtype=np.int64)


%timeit simulate_orig_answer(nyears, rates, alphas, betas, values, rng)
%timeit simulate_warren_answer(nyears, rates, alphas, betas, values, rng)
%timeit simulate_new_rng(nyears, rates, alphas, betas, values, rng)


Thank you for your contribution Nick - this has massively increased performance. I'm wondering whether the low rates mean we could approximate the Poisson distribution with just a Bernoulli distribution of {0, 1} frequencies, possibly using P(freq >= 1) ~= 1 - exp^(-rate) although I'm not sure how much efficiency there is to gain from that vs the beta calculation.

Here's one way you could simulate the annual maximum loss and total loss.  Note that I'm using plain NumPy arrays instead of Pandas.
def simulate(nyears, rate, alpha, beta, value, rng):
    max_loss = np.zeros(nyears, dtype=np.float64)
    total_loss = np.zeros(nyears, dtype=np.float64)
    for year in range(nyears):
        n = rng.poisson(rate)
        k = np.nonzero(n)[0]
        if len(k) > 0:
            nonzero_n = n[k]
            a = np.repeat(alpha[k], nonzero_n)
            b = np.repeat(beta[k], nonzero_n)
            v = np.repeat(value[k], nonzero_n)
            losses = rng.beta(a, b)*v
            max_loss[year] = losses.max()
            total_loss[year] = losses.sum()
    return max_loss, total_loss

It might be a bit faster than your version, but I don't think it will be anything like an order of magnitude faster.
To test it, I used this script:
# Generate some test data.
rng = np.random.default_rng(121263137472525314065)
nevents = 100604
# Other than the mean of the rate being approximately 1, there is no
# special significance to the random distributions used here.
rate = rng.gamma(2, scale=0.5, size=nevents)
alpha = rng.uniform(0.5, 1.5, size=nevents)
beta = rng.uniform(1.25, 2.0, size=nevents)
value = rng.exponential(size=nevents)

nyears = 50000
max_loss, total_loss = simulate(nyears, rate, alpha, beta, value, rng)
print(np.percentile(max_loss, (1 - 1/250) * 100))


Thanks for your response Warren - testing on my actual data this has hugely improved the efficiency of my code, I've included a set of rate/alpha/beta/value calcs now to create a similar(-ish) set of data, the rates are very low with an average of around 1e-5 so this reduced my calculation time on 10,000 years to around 12.8 seconds! I'm interested to see if we can push this further but will approve your solution if no new ideas come around, thank you!

I updated the code to fix a bug. If the rates are low enough, the probability that no events will occur in a year becomes nonnegligible, so that case must be handled.  losses.max() would crash if the length of losses was 0.
